# patent infringement

Tags: infringement

In reference to the patent: [WO2008050157A3](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2008050157A3)

If I wanted to make ozonated oils that were a combination of essential oils and vegetable oils, and then that combination was ozonated, would it be considered conflict of interest with this patent?

Answer (score 0):

It's a PCT application that never entered national phase and is therefore expired.